# Can a dash app be filtered via URL like Power BI

Tags: url, filter, callback, powerbi, plotly-dash

I am embarking on a POC to replace a Power BI dashboard that can’t do all the visualizations we need with a dash app. One major requirement is to be able to pass multiple filters to the app via url in a manner similar to the Power BI capability.

I have tried to research this and see references to URL callbacks and believe this provides the functionality I will need, but I don’t yet understand dash apps well enough to be sure.

I’m not asking how to, just whether or not it can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Use the `dcc.Location` component ([docs](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/location)), and structure any callbacks that need to listen to the URL to have an `Input` based on that component. You can even pass multiple things with it, such as `"filter_1/3/filter_2/5/filter_3/1"` and then `.split('/')` to break up the string and parse the values.